# Bootstrap template is not aligned to the middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have got a little problem. I'm building a template with `twitter-bootstrap` and I got into these two problems. Here you can see my site:

http://jsfiddle.net/e9SGL/embedded/result/ - fullscreen
http://jsfiddle.net/e9SGL/ - small one with code

As you can see the site is not aligned to the center. It is aligned to the right by 5px from the center. I know that it's moved by `padding: 5px;` but I want to keep that padding because it looks weird without it.

The second problem is that text `Mira's Koding`. It is on top of `#logo div`. I want to make it on the bottom of the `#logo div`. Here is my code:

**CSS to bootstrap and my CSS.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/wise.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="display">
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="back">
        <div class="row-fluid" id="logo">
            <div class="span12">Mira's Koding</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid" id="menu">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul class="inline">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid" id="content">
            <div class="span10" id="cleft">
                <h3>Example 1</h3>
                <p>No need of long text here.</p>
                <a href="#">Read more &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a>
                <hr>
                <h3>Example 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</a>
            </div>
            <div class="span2" id="cright">
                <h3>Author</h3>
                <p><i class="icon-envelope"></i> my@mail.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

**wise.css**

```
::selection {
    color:#1f7bac;
}
::-moz-selection {
    color:#1f7bac;
}
html, body {
    background-color: #ebeaea;
    overflow: auto;
}
#back {
    background-color: #ebeaea;
}
#logo {
    background-color: #1f7bac;
    border-left: 1px solid #1f7bac;
    border-right: 1px solid #1f7bac;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;    
}
#menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #1f7bac;
    border-right: 1px solid #1f7bac;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1f7bac;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#content {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #1f7bac;
    padding: 5px;
}
.footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #1f7bac;
    position:fixed; 
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css are not edited. It's default bootstrap CSS.

**Thank you very much.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a number of ways to fix problem #1, but this one does the trick:

```
.row-fluid {
    width: auto;
}
```

As far as problem #2, I don't see a div with ID 'header', but it looks to me like you simply need to move #logo below #menu.

Edit: I see a div#head. Maybe that's what you meant. However, in Firefox #logo is below #head. Please clarify.

Edit again: You could do this:

```
#logo {position: relative;}
#logo > div {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

Again, you have plenty of options.

Comment: Thanks, it works. My mistake, I meant #logo, not #header. Just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all confusion and unnecessary codes, just place

`.container, .container-fluid {margin: 0 auto;}`

This code will align your page to center.

Your second problem is very easy, just dive into css.

Hope it helps.